# renaming a variable in loop using Jython

Tags: python

I apologize if this question has been answered already, but having programming for only a month or so, I was unable to identify an answer as it relates to my particular circumstance.

I will be taking slices from a list, and as I am taking slices from this list through a loop process, I want a particular variable that is assigned to the slices to change its name during each loop process so that I can randomly choose from these variables. So far I have been unable with my limited knowledge to come up with a way to change this variable's name (even something like x1, x2, x3 would be okay with me).

```
for i in range(30):
  z = 0
  measureList = [C4, D4, E4]
  z = len(measureList)
  a = measureList[x:x + z]
  x = x + z
```

Comment: Can you provide some code that highlights what you struggle with? What do you mean by "change its name during each loop process so that I can randomly choose from these variables"?

Comment: I really don't know that my code will be help (it is rather crude). However, I will try to explain my circumstance in more detail.

Comment: I am accessing the list in slices, and I have arrived at a solution to access the slices through indexing. But as the loop goes through its iterations, it assigns a variable name to these slices, and the way I have the process written now, it will assign the same variable name to the slices at each iteration of the loop process, in effect overwriting the information contained in the variable.

Comment: It's easier to refer to actual code (variable names, line numbers) than your description. You don't need to post everything, just the loop is fine, so it's understandable what you're trying to achieve and what your problem is. For instance "I am accessing the list in slices" could mean anything. Are you slicing the list, i.e. `mylist[2:3]` or do you mean you're indexing it? Your terminology may just be off a little, so proposing solutions for something that isn't actually your problem is pointless.

Comment: Ok orange, going to turn in for the night... will try to give you that code tomorrow... many thanks for your patience!

Comment: for i in range(30):

   z = 0

measureList = [C4, D4, E4]

z = len(measureList)

a = measureList[x:x + z]

x = x + z
I would like to have the variable "a" change for each iteration of the loop and have these variables accessible in a random choice process,

Comment: Sorry about the mess in the previous post, If it's too messy, I'll try to repost.

Comment: I've updated your example with your code. Can you try to explain what you want to achieve? `i` in your example isn't doing anything. Do you just want random slices of the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (which is highly unlikely), you'd like to access slices of a list starting at a random index to the end of the list.

Try this:

```
import random

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = len(my_list)

for _ in xrange(30):
  start = random.randint(1, n-2)
  a = my_list[start:]
```

**Update**

> The problem I am having it that when I want to store these created melodies (basically slices from a list), usually a static variable will constantly overwrite the information contained in the melody that was generated in the previous pass of the loop.

I presume the "static variable" you're referring to is `a`. You can just store it in another list. This way you can access it after leaving the loop.

```
import random

my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
n = len(my_list)
other_list = []

for _ in xrange(30):
  start = random.randint(1, n-2)
  a = my_list[start:]
  other_list.append(a)
```

Comment: First I need to ask you, orange...how familiar are you with music? Don't worry if you aren't familiar with it; I think I can adequately express what I want in (mostly) non-musical terms.

Comment: Basically I have a list of midi note numbers (from a particular musical scale) that are used to create melodies.
Each melody lasts a particular amount of time (which uses varying amounts of pitches), and at the end of that time,
I want to create a variable that stores that melody (I have that part of the program figured out).

Comment: As the piece progresses (that's what is happening in the loop), I want additional melodies that are created to be given
a different variable. Sometimes I would like the program to randomly create another melody, but sometimes I would like
for the program to take one of these preexisting melodies and put them in a higher or lower range (I also have that part
of the program figured out).

Comment: The problem I am having it that when I want to store these created melodies (basically slices from a list),
usually a static variable will constantly overwrite the information contained in the melody that was generated in the previous pass of the
loop.

Comment: In case you're wondering, I am a 53 year old sheet music clerk who has a Master's in Music Theory and has been wanting to program my own pieces since I was in my 20's but never quite got to it. I have tried all kinds of prepackaged algorithmic composition programs, and have never been happy using any of them. I am hopeful that I haven't waited too long to start and that I can learn enough programming in the future to do the things I always envisioned composing music with computers.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about music theory.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't gotten back to you sooner orange, but I was doing a little bit more reading on the internet, and found out about dictionaries. The book I am using "Making Music with Computers: Creative Programming in Python" has been an excellent introduction, but nowhere in the book does it mention dictionaries. It seems that storing my lists of notes in a dictionary might be the way to go.

Comment: I have figured out how to put my lists of notes in the dictionary through a for loop process, but I am concerned about one thing in particular. First, the lists of notes I talked about earlier are actually two parallel lists, one of pitches and one of durations. My understanding is that I cannot have one key for two values (lists). If so, I need to be able to set up two dictionaries, one for the lists of pitches, and one for the lists of durations.  They would be read into the dictionaries at the same for loop iteration.

Comment: My main question, then, is: since both lists will be entered into the two dictionaries at the same time as per their for loop iteration, will they be accessible from the two dictionaries at the same location in their respective dictionary (since the key is the same for both lists as per the for loop iteration), can I retrieve them as such?

Comment: You can store two values in a dictionary like `{'key1': {'pitch': pitch_value, 'duration': duration_value}, 'key2': ...}` `pit_value` and `duration_value` can be lists. You can also store them as 2-dimensional list `{'key1': [[...], [...]]}`.

Comment: orange, suppose I had two lists; one [60, 64, 62, 64, 65, 67] (this might be my pitch list], and the other [.50, 1.0, .25, .25, 1.0, 1.0] (this might be my duration list), and I want to assign them to a two dimension dictionary (of your two suggestions, this one sounds like the one I want).

Comment: For example,I would like for key1 to be the first key coming from the loop iterator, assign the first list item in my pitch list (60) to your pitch_value list and assign the first list item of my duration list (.50) to your duration_value list, and then continue going through the rest of the iterations of the for loop process and assign the rest of the list items of my two lists one by one?

Comment: There's no need to iterate through any keys or values: Just assign these lists to the dictionary `my_dict = {'key1': [pit_list, duration_list]}`.

Comment: The problem though is that I do not know what list items are that will be contained in the lists! I want the program to go through a process where it will select the pitch and duration lists items for the two lists one pitch and one duration at a time (I have this part of the program figured out). It is through the for loop process that I plan to make this happen.

Comment: As the iterations of the for loop process occurs, it is building the list items for the two lists one list item at a time. I have designated a certain point where the lists are considered complete, and on the next iteration of the for loop another list of pitches and list of durations will be created and the list items generated one at a time as before.

Comment: In other words, I would like to have one key be able to reference both the pitch list [60, 64, 62, 64, 65, 67] and the duration list [.50, 1.0, .25, .25, 1.0, 1.0]. Is this possible?

Comment: You can also store them as 2-dimensional list {'key1': [[...], [...]]}

Comment: It took me a while, but I think this is what I was looking for all along! my_dict = {'key1': [pitch_list, duration_list]}. Many thanks orange!